# Logic check not outputting as expected. (Sudoku checker) C

Tags: c, multithreading, sudoku

I have a function that checks all the rows of a sudoku board and outputs and exits if invalid.

(a valid row has 1-9 on a 9 square row)

I've been staring at my logic for 30 minutes and can't see why a board that I know is valid keeps spitting out invalid.

To try and make it a little easier to read, here's the part in question...

```
void* checkRow(void* p){

  int check[9] = {0};
  parameters* temp = (parameters*) p;
  int tempRow = temp -> row;
  int tempCol = temp -> col;

  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){ // looping to find each # 1-9

    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){

      if (board[i][j] == 1)
          check[0] = 1;
      if (board[i][j] == 2)
          check[1] = 1;
      if (board[i][j] == 3)
          check[2] = 1;
      if (board[i][j] == 4)
          check[3] = 1;
      if (board[i][j] == 5)
          check[4] = 1;
      if (board[i][j] == 6)
          check[5] = 1;
      if (board[i][j] == 7)
          check[6] = 1;
      if (board[i][j] == 8)
          check[7] = 1;
      if (board[i][j] == 9) // changing value to 1 if found
          check[8] = 1;

      int k = 0;
      while(k < 9){
          if (check[k] == 0){
          printf("invalid solution"); // should only print if 1-9 isn't found right?
          exit(0);
          }
      k++;
      }

      memset(check, 0, sizeof(check)); // resetting array to zero

    }

  }

}
```

Here's everything, just in case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define SIZE 9

typedef struct{ // referenced from assignment page
  int row;
  int col;
} parameters;

int board[SIZE][SIZE]; // global variable holding board

pthread_t tRow, tCol, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9;

void setThreads();
void* checkRow(void* p);

int main(int argc, char **argv){ // referenced project 1. Supplies command line input for file

  FILE *fp;

  fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

  if (fp == NULL) // validity check
    exit(1);

  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
          fscanf(fp, "%d", &board[i][j]);
      }
  }

  setThreads();
  printf("rows check out");

  return 0;

}

void setThreads(){

  parameters *rowcolparameter = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
  rowcolparameter -> row = 0;
  rowcolparameter -> col = 0;

  parameters *square1 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
  square1 -> row = 0;
  square1 -> col = 0;

  parameters *square2 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
  square2 -> row = 0;
  square2 -> col = 3;

  parameters *square3 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
  square3 -> row = 0;
  square3 -> col = 6;

  parameters *square4 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
  square4 -> row = 3;
  square4 -> col = 0;

  parameters *square5 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
  square5 -> row = 3;
  square5 -> col = 3;

  parameters *square6 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
  square6 -> row = 3;
  square6 -> col = 6;

  parameters *square7 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
  square7 -> row = 6;
  square7 -> col = 0;

  parameters *square8 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
  square8 -> row = 6;
  square8 -> col = 3;

  parameters *square9 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
  square9 -> row = 6;
  square9 -> col = 6;

  pthread_create(&tRow, NULL, checkRow, rowcolparameter);

  pthread_join(tRow, NULL);

}

void* checkRow(void* p){

  int check[9] = {0};
  parameters* temp = (parameters*) p;
  int tempRow = temp -> row;
  int tempCol = temp -> col;

  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){ // looping to find each # 1-9

    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){

      if (board[i][j] == 1)
          check[0] = 1;
      if (board[i][j] == 2)
          check[1] = 1;
      if (board[i][j] == 3)
          check[2] = 1;
      if (board[i][j] == 4)
          check[3] = 1;
      if (board[i][j] == 5)
          check[4] = 1;
      if (board[i][j] == 6)
          check[5] = 1;
      if (board[i][j] == 7)
          check[6] = 1;
      if (board[i][j] == 8)
          check[7] = 1;
      if (board[i][j] == 9)
          check[8] = 1;

    int k = 0;
    while(k < 9){
    if (check[k] == 0){
      printf("invalid solution"); // it should only say invalid if 1-9 wasn't found right?
      exit(0);
    }
    k++;
      }

      memset(check, 0, sizeof(check)); // resetting array to 0

    }

  }

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to step through your code statement by statement in a debugger? If it doesn't help, go to bed, sleep well, and eat a big and healthy breakfast, then try again with the debugger.

Comment: All the allocations in the `setThreads` function leads to a lot of memory leaks. Also, `pthread_create` *directly* followed by `pthread_join` is no better than just calling the thread function, it will not run multiple threads in parallel but in serial.

Comment: Will the memory leaks still be an issue once I implement code for columns and 3x3 squares like I am doing for rows? This is new territory to me.

Comment: You need to `free` what you `malloc`. As long as you do that you won't have any leaks. And a general tip: Don't add things you don't currently need. Adding code adds complexity, and sometimes when resources are involved (like allocating memory) you could have leaks that can be easily avoided. When you need `square1` then add code for its allocation, when you need `square2` then add the code for its allocation.

Comment: Also, if you have a lot of code that does the same thing, then consider using loops. You could make all of `rowcolparameter`, `square1` etc. into an array. Or maybe just allocate locally inside the loop where you start the threads, and let the threads themselves `free` the memory, and you don't need even an array (much less separate variables).

Comment: Is it the same idea as a destructor in C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the "check part" is **inside** the inner loop! Shouldn't it be **outside** the inner loop. Like:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){ // looping to find each # 1-9

    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){

      if (board[i][j] == 1)
          check[0] = 1;
      if (board[i][j] == 2)
          check[1] = 1;
      if (board[i][j] == 3)
          check[2] = 1;
      if (board[i][j] == 4)
          check[3] = 1;
      if (board[i][j] == 5)
          check[4] = 1;
      if (board[i][j] == 6)
          check[5] = 1;
      if (board[i][j] == 7)
          check[6] = 1;
      if (board[i][j] == 8)
          check[7] = 1;
      if (board[i][j] == 9) // changing value to 1 if found
          check[8] = 1;
    }  // End the inner loop

    // Now do the check
    int k = 0;
    while(k < 9){
       if (check[k] == 0){
         printf("invalid solution"); // should only print if 1-9 isn't found right?
         exit(0);
       }
       k++;
    }

    memset(check, 0, sizeof(check)); // resetting array to zero

  }
```

BTW: you can reduce the inner-loop code a lot like this:

```
  // inner loop
  for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
      if (board[i][j] < 1 || board[i][j] > 9) exit(1); // Illegal board value

      check[board[i][j] - 1] = 1;  // Mark value as found
  }
```

Comment: Oh my God lol. I haven't coded in so long I didn't even notice!

Comment: Thank you btw. For that and the cleanup tip.